# How to power off USB stick or MMC card under linux?

Tags: linux, usb, power-management

Usually I just unmount the usb stick or mmc before unplugging it but I'd prefer to turn the power off before doing so. I think Windows does this, so the hardware should allow for turning off the power to a specific port but I don't know how to do this on a recent linux kernel (I am not sure if suspending is really the same but afaik it is deprecated/removed from recent kernels anyway).
If you know how to do this, please explain. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is really no reason why you would want to do this: pulling the stick/card out kills the power already, so turning off the USB port would be redundant. Also, how would the computer know when to turn the power back on, to prepare for another device being attached?

There is a related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163824/linux-usb-turning-the-power-on-and-off. To summarize, you generally can't turn the power off on ports off a motherboard, though some hubs might support this. USB has "suspend", but this is just your computer telling the device to turn itself off, power is still given through the USB port.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is command to "power off" USB sticks and USB drives. I don't think it really physically cuts the power from the USB port, but it tells the USB stick or drive to become inactive so it can be safely removed. That's what Windows calls "Eject" and it does not really eject the stick either.

```
udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdX
```

(Replace X by the letter of your USB stick/drive, it's only a letter. Use `lsblk` to find the correct one if unsure. Do not use a letter and a number. That would be a partition and it cannot be "powered off".)

MMC cards don't support that protocol. So the command will not work for them.